# How to use {:autocontracts}?

Tags: dafny

The official documentation says:

```
From the user’s perspective, what needs to be done is simply:
1. mark the class with {:autocontracts}
2. declare a function (or predicate) called Valid()
```

But after doing that, nothing happens. There's no autocontracts button or command in VSCode either, and nothing anywhere that says what to do after that.

What do I have to do to make Dafny auto-generate autocontracts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do above compiler adds

- `Valid()` as post condition in constructor
- `Valid()` as precondition and post condition in methods
- Some precondition and post condition about `Repr` and `this`

Lets look at this class definition

```
class {:autocontracts true} TestClass {
    var n: int;

    ghost predicate Valid() 
    {
       n >= 0 
    }

    constructor TestClass() {
       n := 0;
    }

    method Update(m: int) 
    {
       this.n := m;
    }
}
```

If you hover over constructor you see that `Valid()` post-condition is added to constructor. [image]

Further `Valid()` precondition and post condition is added to method `Update`. [image]

Because of this `Update` method is not able to verify and you need extra precondition that `m >= 0`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realise I had to hover over the methods/functions/predicates. I was expecting some sort of auto-complete to occur.

Comment: autocontracts is a bit of an experimental feature. The contracts it auto-generates for you are, more or less, the ones described as idioms in chapter 16 (in particular, section 16.4) of "Program Proofs" (https://mitpress.mit.edu/9780262546232/program-proofs/). In lieu of more detailed documentation, the hover texts that @Divyanshu Ranjan pointed out are the best guide for understanding what you get. If you have suggestions for how to improve this experimental feature, please file bugs/feature requests to https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/issues. Pull requests are welcome, too.